# Correct Paths for Java Spring with Angular UI-router

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc, angular-ui-router

I've been trying to implement ui-router with spring but all I am getting is a bunch of 404s in the browser.  I cannot seem to get the path names correctly so ui-router cannot properly switch the view.  I've looked at similar problems on SO, but cannot get it working.

Is there a specific way I need to structure my project so that the path names work?  I thought that UI-router's `templateURL` worked from the root of the project, so I tried putting a path name that started at the project root but to no success.  I am building the project using maven in intellij as well, so I am unsure if that is affecting the problem at all.

[image: Here is how the project is structured]

I have my controller ui-router structured like this:

```
var myMod = angular.module("myMod", ['ui.router'])
    .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/first');

    $stateProvider
        .state('first', {
            url: '/first',
            templateUrl: '/UIProject/src/main/resources/static/templates/database.html',
            controller: 'BookingsController'
        })
}]);
```

my HTML template is structured like:

```
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" ng-app="myMod">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <script src="../static/angular.min.js" th:src="@{/angular.min.js}"></script>
    <script src="../static/app/bookings.controller.js" th:src="@{/app/bookings.controller.js}"></script>
    <script src="../static/angular-ui-router.min.js" th:src="@{/angular-ui-router.min.js}"></script>

</head>

<body ng-controller="BookingsController">
<p>THIS IS A PROJECT</p>
<ui-view></ui-view>

</body>
</html>
```

and I also have the `database.html` file in the same folder as `index.html` (templates)

Comment: You may wanna have a public folder and expose it with your server. Then the server can resolve those paths: `/public/templates/....` or you could create mappings: `/public/templates` -> `/UIProject/src/main/resources/static/templates`

Comment: i found that it was using `/static` as the root for the file paths.  So I got it working and can now change the file paths accordingly!  but thanks for your input.  I also realized I had the wrong project name in the original filepath so it wouldn't have worked anyway.